# Is there a way to convert an ISO week number to datetime format without year or day data

Tags: python, python-datetime

I'm trying to change a short string containing an ISO week number like this:
`"W24"`
Into a datetime object where the rest of the data are filled with arbitrary values like this:
`datetime.datetime(yyyy,6,12,s,ms)`

I know the strptime function can do this when only the year, month, or day is provided. However, when I try this with only an ISO week number, I receive an error because I need the ISO year and day as well:

```
ValueError: ISO week directive '%V' must be used with the ISO year directive '%G' and a weekday directive ('%A', '%a', '%w', or '%u').
```

Is there a way to get around this limitation without having to change the original string? Thanks in advance

Comment: A ISO week number contains multiple days, but `datetime.datetime` represents a specific time during **a** day. Week 24 of different years will contain different days. What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `year` to do that. You can generate one randomly.

```
import random
from datetime import datetime

# Week value
week = 'W24'

# Generate a random year. It's mandatory
random_year = random.randint(1990, 2023)

# Generate proper date string
date = str(random_year) + "-" + week

# Convert it to datetime object
res = datetime.strptime(date + '-1', '%G-W%V-%u')

print(res)
```

Result:

```
2000-06-12 00:00:00
```

Comment: Of course, the result will only be correct something like 1/7 of the time. (Slightly more, but generally indicative.)